# What process is changing my file permissions?

Tags: mojave, permission, file

Every once in a while, I notice that *something* must have recursively changed all my files' permissions in my home directory to `go-rx` — so I do:

```
$ find . -type f -exec chmod go+r {} \;
$ find . -type d -exec chmod go+rx {} \;
```

to put it back to the way I want it — for a little while until whatever thing changes the permissions again. But what process is periodically changing my file permissions (and how can I *stop* it)?

Comment: Why are you hosting a web site from your *home* directory?

Comment: Because it's something small that only I maintain. But my reason _doesn't matter_. If you can actually _answer_ the question (and not second-guess _why_ I'm doing it in a particular way), please do. It it makes it easier for you, just totally forget that I'm running a web site. Consider my question to have been _only_: "What process is changing my file permissions of my home directory?"

Comment: Actually it *does* matter.  If you're running a website *from* your home directory, I'm trying to determine how you've configured `httpd.conf`, what permissions you've changed to give access to Apache given that the home directory itself has permissions specific to macOS.  And if you're executing those `chmod` commands on your `home` directory, you're potentially breaking other things and/or macOS is using a higher privileged process to restore the correct ones

Comment: We can debate what process is doing what (use `lsof`) but that would be pointless if you decided to make your `DocumentRoot` your whole home directory.  It's a better idea to create a folder just for it and give the appropriate permissions to the web server process.

Comment: I never said the document root is my whole home directory. I'm allowing `~user` directories, the entire point of which is to allow users to serve the own pages. But, again, it _doesn't matter_. On a different Mac (where I'm _not_ running a web server), presumably the same mystery process is also changing the permissions of my home directory — except _there_, I don't really care as much since nobody else needs to see files there. But I'd still like to know what that process is and _stop_ it from touching file permissions.

Comment: There: I've edited my question to remove any mention of any web server because, as I've said repeatedly, it _doesn't matter_.

Comment: You can pound your head against the wall as much as you like.  There are reasons that things are done a certain way. Get with the program.